# why toggleCategories function does not work, only displays sequence number 0. ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a portfolio with react, I created a project page in which there are several projects that are created in Tabs, but that doesn't work as I want.

```
 toggleCategories(){
     if(this.state.activeTab === 0){
         return(
             <div><h1>Hello React</h1></div>
         )
     }else if(this.state.activeTab === 1){
         return(
             <div><h1>Hello Vue</h1></div>
         )
     }else if(this.state.activeTab === 2){
         return(
             <div><h1>Hello NodeJs</h1></div>
         )
     }
 }

render(){
    return (
       <div className="categories-tabs">
        <Tabs activeTab={this.state.activeTab} onchange={(tabId) => this.setState({ activeTab: tabId})} ripple>
            <Tab>React</Tab>
            <Tab>VueJs</Tab>
            <Tab>NodeJs</Tab>
            <Tab>Laravel</Tab>                
        </Tabs>

        <section className="project-grids">
            {this.toggleCategories()}
        </section>
       </div>
    )
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code?  It's hard for me to understand what is going on with `Tabs` and `Tab`.  Are you using styled-components or something?

Comment: Please create stackblitz link so we can understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` supposed to be `onChange` React's synthetic event in order for your toggle function to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use something like:

```
<div className="categories-tabs">
    <Tabs>
      <Tab>React</Tab>
      <Tab>VueJs</Tab>
      <Tab>NodeJs</Tab>
      <Tab>Laravel</Tab>

      <TabPanel>
        <div>
          <h1>Hello React</h1>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel>
        <div>
          <h1>Hello Vue</h1>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel>
        <div>
          <h1>Hello NodeJs</h1>
        </div>
      </TabPanel>
    </Tabs>
  </div>
```

This looks like the way it is meant to be used

But if you want to handle view options using state then you can use

```
defaultIndex={0}
onSelect={index => this.setState({ activeTab: index })}
```

instead of

```
activeTab={this.state.activeTab}
onchange={tabId => {
  this.setState({ activeTab: tabId });
}}
ripple
```

If you console.log your `onchange` (it should be `onChange` by the way if we are talking about React synthetic events) then you can see that nothing happens on tab selection. You just need to use correct properties to pass your handlers